# react-native Ios AWS pinpoint notifications not receiving on testflight

Tags: react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

My app receives remote push notification when in development and when built with MSAppCenter for release build .
But on the app submitted to testflight notification are not being received .
I have created a ANPS certificate for Sandbox and Production and uploaded it on pinpoint for sandbox and production .

I can confirm that pinpoint  endpoints are being created for user on testflight app but that is it no notifications.

I have seen multiple threads about this issue but nothing seems to be explain what to do. nor am i understanding where to debug.

packages used in the app:
`"aws-amplify": "^3.3.17"`
`"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0"`
`"@aws-amplify/pushnotification": "^3.2.20"`

Any Help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured out the issue.
this is because of `ChannelType` in AWS sdk pinpoint sendMessage.
Have to  use `APNS` to push notifications to production devices and `APNS_SANDBOX` for staging devices .

```
pinpoint.sendMessages({..., MessageRequest: {..., Addresses: {
                               ["<Address>"]: {
                                ChannelType: "APNS"
                            }
                        }}
```

Even tho my cert is for staging and production using channelType as `APNS` is only pushing for production(release) app.